# How do I install PHP 5.2.4 on Linux Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: php, installation

I've looked on  php.net and ubuntu.com and can not find the relevant documentation.

When I run sudo apt-get install from the terminal it installs PHP 5.3.3, which I am currently using.

If there are binaries available great, if I have to compile them that is fine, if I need to re-install the OS for compatibility that is fine.  I just need a path to get to PHP 5.2.4.

Comment: So in the title, you actually mean PHP *5*.2.4? Currently reads 2.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link might help you:

http://www.nickveenhof.be/blog/reverting-or-downgrade-php-53-52-ubuntu-lucid-lynx-1004

Comment: Thanks, that is good info.  Does not seem like a quick few commands.

Comment: The real situation is choosing between binaries or going apt-get. I'm not sure either is a bad method. Compiling binaries could be fun :)

Comment: I need a direct method, the link is cool but it installs based upon Ubutnu version (replaces lucid with karmic), I need to install based upon version number.  Either the binary or from source.

Comment: Found the source files at...http://php.net/releases/index.php. Found install directions at...http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/07/instruction-guide-to-install-php5-from-source-on-linux/. Need a reference for setting the configuration before running "make" and "make install".

Comment: The geekstuff.com has 3 tutorials that explain how to install from source Apache, MySQL, and PHP.  Went with the default configurations used in the tutorials b.c. I don't have time to research all the different options.  Both are working great.  This is the best site I've found for Linux and "superuser" type tutorials.  Here it is again...

    http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/07/instruction-guide-to-install-php5-from-source-on-linux/

Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 2? or 5?

Try this resource (use google translator, it's in portuguese, still you can clearly see the commands) http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Instalacao-(downgrade)-PHP-5.2.x-no-Ubuntu-10.04